# Error: We found the libraries for libevent, but we could not find the C header files

Tags: ubuntu, debian, tor, libevent, c-header

I´m trying to install an old Tor version which requires a libevent devel package.

I have downloaded a devel package correctly, but and when I run `./configure --with-libevent-dir=/libevent/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, I´m getting this output:

```
We found the libraries for libevent, but we could not find the C header files. 
You may need to install a devel package
```

This is the tree of libevent folder

```
libevent
├── include
│   ├── evdns.h
│   ├── event2
│   │   ├── buffer_compat.h
│   │   ├── bufferevent_compat.h
│   │   ├── bufferevent.h
│   │   ├── bufferevent_ssl.h
│   │   ├── bufferevent_struct.h
│   │   ├── buffer.h
│   │   ├── dns_compat.h
│   │   ├── dns.h
│   │   ├── dns_struct.h
│   │   ├── event_compat.h
│   │   ├── event-config.h
│   │   ├── event.h
│   │   ├── event_struct.h
│   │   ├── http_compat.h
│   │   ├── http.h
│   │   ├── http_struct.h
│   │   ├── keyvalq_struct.h
│   │   ├── listener.h
│   │   ├── rpc_compat.h
│   │   ├── rpc.h
│   │   ├── rpc_struct.h
│   │   ├── tag_compat.h
│   │   ├── tag.h
│   │   ├── thread.h
│   │   └── util.h
│   ├── event.h
│   ├── evhttp.h
│   ├── evrpc.h
│   └── evutil.h
├── lib
│   └── x86_64-linux-gnu
│       ├── libevent.a
│       ├── libevent_core.a
│       ├── libevent_core.so -> libevent_core-2.0.so.5.1.9
│       ├── libevent_extra.a
│       ├── libevent_extra.so -> libevent_extra-2.0.so.5.1.9
│       ├── libevent_openssl.a
│       ├── libevent_openssl.so -> libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5.1.9
│       ├── libevent_pthreads.a
│       ├── libevent_pthreads.so -> libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5.1.9
│       ├── libevent.so -> libevent-2.0.so.5.1.9
│       └── pkgconfig
│           ├── libevent_openssl.pc
│           ├── libevent.pc
│           └── libevent_pthreads.pc
└── share
    └── doc
        └── libevent-dev
```

How can I solve this issue?